# How to execute sql command and read its return value when the column has no name

Tags: c#

I've been using SqlDataReader to read results from my querys to an SQL server db.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
   Console.WriteLine(rdr["ColumnName"].ToString());
}
```

But now I want to create a Job in my C# program, and when I do that, the return value (the ID of the created job), comes in a column with no name.

How to execute sql command and read its return value when the column has no name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve the column by index: `rdr[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Use an integer index instead of a column name, eg.:

```
rdr[0].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Either address the column by index as others have proposed, or, better yet, specify a new name for the column within the query using the `AS` keyword. For example, `SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM XYZ` will give the count column the name `C`.